expect: not being able to know when a spawned command ends
My application/process is running in HostA. It needs to connect to HostB using user and password (public key authentication not allowed) in order to send another script and a command file. Then, I need to connect to HostB and remotely execute that script, which connects to HostC using public key authentication to actually generate the export file.
In HostA I have this script (script_in_HostA.sh)
#!/bin/bash

user=myuser
password=mypassword
HostB=myHostB_name
WKDIR=${HOME}/utils

# [1] Send "generate_export.sh" to HostB using SCP, using ${user} and ${password} variables
expect -c "
  set timeout 600
  spawn scp -q -p -P 5023 ${WKDIR}/generate_export.sh ${user}@${HostB}:./generate_export.sh
  match_max 100000
  expect "*?assword:*"
  send \"${password}\r\"
  send \"\r\"
  expect eof"

# [2] Send commands file  to HostB using SCP, using ${user} and ${password} variables
expect -c "
  set timeout 600
  spawn scp -q -p -P 5023 ${WKDIR}/commands.cmd ${user}@${HostB}:./commands.cmd
  match_max 100000
  expect "*?assword:*"
  send \"${password}\r\"
  send \"\r\"
  expect eof"

# [3] Remotely execute generate_export.sh in HostB
output_file=results.txt
expect -c "
  set timeout 3600
  spawn ssh -q -p 5023 ${user}@${HostB} sh ./generate_export.sh ./commands.cmd ./${output_file}
  match_max 100000
  expect "*?assword:*"
  send \"${password}\r\"
  send \"\r\"
  expect END
  exit"

echo "I have finished"

generate_export.sh looks like this
#!/bin/bash

# Args
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
    command_file=$1
    output_file=$2
else
    # Incorrect number of args
    exit 10
fi

SCRIPTNAME=$(basename $0)
USER=username_in_HostC
host=HostC
export_command=/usr/local/bin/appexport

# Connection to HostC
echo -e "$(date '+%Y%m%d %H%M%S') ..${SCRIPTNAME}.. START ${command_file}"
# Public key authentication, no password or "expect" needed
ssh ${USER}@${host} ${export_command} -file ${HOME}/${command_file} > ${HOME}/${output_file}
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "$(date '+%Y%m%d %H%M%S') ..${SCRIPTNAME}.. END ${command_file}"
    gzip -f ${HOME}/${output_file}
    #exit 0
else
    # Error code
    exit 20
fi

When I execute script_in_HostA.sh in HostA, it sends generate_export.sh and commands.cmd to HostB, and then it remotely executes
generate_export.sh -file commands.cmd > results.txt

The desired result is results.txt.gz and that's what I see. I can use another terminal to connect to HostA, HostB and HostC and I see that results.txt.gz has been generated.
However, script_in_HostA.sh gets stuck in step [3]. It looks like script_in_HostA.sh doesn't notice the spawned SSH has ended and it can continue on to write "I have finished". I can execute ps in HostA and see expect and ssh still running after the .txt.gz file has been generated.
I have tried
expect eof

instead of
expect END
exit

but it doesn't work.
I am using "expect END" because that's what generate_export.sh writes to stdout when it has generated the export.
If generate_export.sh ends in HostB, why doesn't HostA realise it has finished?
Thanks in advance.

What does generate_export.sh do? Does it launch any processes that continue running after generate_export.sh exits?

No, generate_export.sh calls ssh to connect to HostC, where it launches some export that eventually ends and the results are gzipped (as I can see later) and finally exits without any background process left behind.

Connect and authenticate to Host B once, using the -M option, then use separate ssh commands to connect over the master connection password-free.

@chepner Do you mean using one ssh -M (or ssh -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/%r@%h:%p), keep it open doing nothing, and using other ssh/scp in separate scripts?

Yes. The master stays open in the background for as long as you need, and is the only command spawned by except. The others are simply run as normal foreground jobs, and when they complete, use ssh -O exit ... to close the master.

Just use expect to start an authenticated control master, which other processes can use without explicitly authenticating again. Once they have completed, you can manually close the master connection. (Further, once scp command can copy both files to the remote host, as you aren't changing the file name on the remote end.)
Something like
#!/bin/bash

user=myuser
password=mypassword
HostB=myHostB_name
WKDIR=${HOME}/utils
socket=~/.ssh/%C

expect -c "
  spawn ssh -N -p 5023 $user@HostB -o ControlMaster -o ControlPath=\"$socket\"
  match_max 100000
  expect \"*?assword:*\"
  send \"${password}\r\"
  send \"\r\"
  expect eof"


scp -o "ControlPath=$socket" -q -p -P 5023 \
   "${WKDIR}/generate_export.sh" \ 
   "${WKDIR}/commands.cmd" \
   ${user}@${HostB}:
       
ssh -o "ControlPath=$socket" -q -p 5023 ${user}@${HostB} "sh ./generate_export.sh ./commands.cmd ./${output_file}"
  
ssh -o "ControlPath=$socket" -O exit

echo "I have finished"


I am running a modified version of my script according to your sugestions, but the scp doesn't start. Maybe because of the previous expect eof? If the -N option doesn't execute a command, is expect eof actually waiting for something and that's why the following scp doesn't execute? It is as if the master doen's leave control to the following statements.
I have tried  with exit instead of expect eof, or just with neither, and it seems in that case the socket ends and the following scp asks for a password.

Possibly; I'm not sure what that line does. You aren't waiting for that ssh process to end, though, and it's not producing any output, so you can proceed as soon as it "exits". It appears I forgot to add the -f flag, which is what makes ssh background itself once authentication is complete.

I finally did this:
expect -c "spawn ssh -N .... expect eof" &
Notice the & at the end. I guess it is equivalent to ssh -f"

However, generate_export.sh generates the gzipped file I need but the ssh that invokes it doesn't return. It doesn't realise it has ended.
To solve it, I modified generate_export.sh to write a control file when exiting, lauched the calling ssh in background and looped every N seconds to test for the existence of the remote control file. Afterwards, the main script scp-copies the results file and deletes generate_export.sh, commands.cmd and the control

Thank you @chepner for your insight
